# How can I inherit a UIScrollView like what the UITableView do?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to create a scroll view filled with grid cell of irregular size.

The `UITableView`, inheriting the `UIScrollView`, alloc cells effectively.
I just want to do the same.

Of couse, it is possible to use `UIScrollViewDelegate` to detect scroll event.  But that will hold the delegate property.  I want to use the delegate property as it used to be.  So I have to inherit the `UIScrollView` as the `UITableView` does.

The question is how to do that?
Which method should I override to get the scroll event?

Comment: You need to clarify your question a bit -- it's not clear to me exactly what you're asking. Have you read the UIScrollView API docs?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to implement cells with arbitrary heights, then you could simply implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and you can decide the height for each cell in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You should watch the WWDC 2010 video for UIScrollView, which includes lots of information about how to lay out many views. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

You could also look at the [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080) example code for how to tile many views.